# How to add settings json to .exe file for selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testing, automated-tests

Im am pointing to an app to use as my driver on selenium

```
public static WebDriver startDriverTwo() {
        String projectLocation = System.getProperty("user.dir");
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", projectLocation + "/chromedriver.exe");

        ChromeOptions opt = new ChromeOptions();
        //Enter the path of your app
        opt.setBinary("C:/pathtoapp.exe");
        //opt.setBinary()
        opt.addArguments("start-maximized");
        driver = new ChromeDriver(opt);
        System.out.println("opening app");
        return driver;
```

However i need to add a settings.json file to this application to work correctly, is it possible to add this file in the DriverFactory? The application works correctly when launched outside of selenium just when run from selenium its not working correctly